# Django form rendering isn't passing along original HTTP request object

Tags: django, django-forms

New to Django/Python/stackexchange...

I have a Jquery Datatable and I'm having difficulty passing along the value of a cell (called email_id) of the table as an HTTP parm to be used when handling a new form page.

The view is initially receiving the request correctly per the debug output:

```
WSGIRequest: GET '/main_app/makeTask/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=gDeTwaNfGNLO7cdMk1
B9gsdpcGYpKAyL&email_id=14d2a002852e1738'
```

It successfully extracts email_id with request.GET.get() on the first call (then proceeds to construct the form and render it) but it gets dropped when the form is being rendered.  I.e., email_msg_id is extracted correctly on the GET but not on the subsequent POST.

Here is the extraction code along with the render statement.  The problem is the 'email_id' is not propagating when I render the form so it cannot be used by view when it processes the form input.

```
email_msg_id = request.GET.get('email_id', "GET - no email_id")
...
return render(request, 'main_app/makeTask.html', {'form': form, 'email_id': email_msg_id})
```

Debug message:

```
<WSGIRequest: GET '/main_app/makeTask.html'>
```

Here are relevant sections of urls.py:

```
url(r'^makeTask', views.make_task, name='makeTask'),
```

My Jquery call (which appears to be working/passing along the email_ID correctly:

```
$('#make_task').click( function () {
        alert( table.cell('.selected',4).data()+' Converted to Task');
        // alert(table.cell('.selected',0).data()+' Make Task selected:');
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/main_app/makeTask/",
            data: { 
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}',
                'email_id' : table.cell('.selected',4).data(),
            },
            success: makeTaskSuccess,
            dataType: 'html'
        }); 
        function makeTaskSuccess(data)
        {
            alert('Convert email to task ');
        }
    } );
```

Here is the view (with unrelated stuff removed):

```
def make_task(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        email_msg_id = request.GET.get('email_id', "GET - no email_id")     # from the post dictionary of the request object passed in

    else:
        email_msg_id = request.POST.get('email_id', "POST - no email_id")

    print "EMAIL_MSG_ID: ", email_msg_id, "METHOD: ", request.method

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MakeTaskForm(request.POST or None)       # Create a form instance and populate it with the data

        if form.is_valid():
            # process and save to db
            #...

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('main_app.views.index'))

        else:
            print form.errors
        return
    else:
        form = MakeTaskForm()

        return render(request, 'main_app/makeTask.html', {'form': form, 'email_id': email_msg_id})
        #return render(request, 'main_app/makeTask.html', context_dict)
```

UPDATE: added relevant template code:

```
<form id="make_task_form" method="post" action="/main_app/makeTask/", method="Post">
    {% csrf_token %}                                                                                
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Due Date: &nbsp</label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="due_selection" id="optionsRadiosInline1" value="TODAY" {{ form.due_selection }} Today
                </label>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12">                                
            <p>Specific Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" {{ form.due_date }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-med" id="btn-make-task">
                Make Task
            </button>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-2x pull-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you init the form in the template?

Comment: Is this what you are requesting?

Comment: I ended up accomplishing my objective by using a simple session variable.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you posted I assume you're using `GET` for AJAX and `POST` in your form.

The form code you posted is wrong, access your form fields in your template like this (also get rid of the duplicated `method` attribute in `<form>`):

```
<form id="make_task_form" method="post" action="/main_app/makeTask/">
    {% csrf_token %}                                                                                
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-xs-12">
            {{ form.due_selection }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12">                                
            {{ form.due_date }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-med" id="btn-make-task">
                Make Task
            </button>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-2x pull-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

To use `<input type="radio">` for the field `due_selection` you should specify the [RadioSelect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/widgets/#radioselect) widget in your `ModelForm` class:

```
CHOICES = (('1', 'First',), ('2', 'Second',))
due_selection = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=CHOICES)
```

Comment: Thanks - all good suggestions - much more maintainable.  I made the updates as suggested (in a couple of locations).  And I converted to an inline radio button by using widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizRadioRenderer).   Unfortunately this didn't resolve my issue.  Specifically, the first call (from the ajax click function) correctly passes email_id to the view but this call from the view: return render(request, 'main_app/makeTask.html', {'form': form, 'email_id': email_msg_id}) doesn't seem to be passing it.  Passing as context_dict also did not work.  I'm looking into hidden fields now